# Implementing Transaction in Entity Framework UnitOfWork patterns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, transactions, foreign-keys, unit-of-work

I have a web app using MVC and EF. I am using [Repository and Unit of Work Patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) from Microsoft online doc.
I am trying to insert multiple rows from multiple tables.
The code look something like this:

```
unitOfWork.Table1.Insert(row1);
unitOfWork.Save();//recId is primary key, will be auto generated after save.

table2Row.someId = table1Row.recId;
unitOfWork.Table2.Insert(row2);
unitOfWork.Save();
```

If anything goes wrong when inserting row2, I need to rollback row1 and row2.
How do I implement BeginTransaction/Commit/Rollback with UnitOfWork pattern?

Thanks.

Comment: you only need to call unitOfWork.Save() once when you are done.

Comment: Why do you implement a pattern that you don't understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid these issues it is better to utilize EF as an ORM rather than a simple data translation service by using reference properties rather than relying on setting FK values directly.

Your example doesn't really appear to be providing anything more than a thin abstraction of the DbContext.

Given an example of an Order for a new Customer where you want a CustomerId to be present on the Order.

Problem: the new Customer's ID is generated by the DB, so it will only be available after SaveChanges.

Solution: Use EF navigation properties and let EF manage the FKs.

```
var customer = new Customer
{
   Name = customerName,
   // etc.
};
var order = new Order
{
    OrderNumber = orderNumber,
    // etc.
    Customer = customer,
};
dbContext.Orders.Add(order);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Note that we didn't have to add the Customer to the dbContext explicitly, it will be added via the order's Customer reference and the Order table's CustomerId will be set automatically. If there is a Customers DbSet on the context you can add the customer explicitly as well, but only one SaveChanges call is needed.

To set the navigation properties up see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50539429/423497

** Edit (based on comments on 1-many relationships) **
For collections some common traps to avoid would include setting the collection references directly for entities that have already been associated with the DbContext, and also utilizing virtual references so that EF can best manage the tracking of instances in the collection.

If an order has multiple customers then you would have a customers collection in the order:

```
public virtual List<Customer> Customers{ get; set; } = new List<Customer>();
```

and optionally an Order reference in your customer:

```
public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
```

Mapping these would look like: (from the Order perspective)

```
HasMany(x => x.Customers)
  .WithRequired(x => x.Order)
  .Map(x => x.MapKey("OrderId"));
```

or substitute `.WithRequired()` if the customer does not have an Order reference.

This is based on relationships where the entities do not have FK fields declared. If you declare FKs then `.Map(...)` becomes `.HasForeignKey(x => x.FkProperty)`

From there if you are creating a new order:

```
var order = new Order 
{ 
  OrderNumber = "12345", 
  Customers = new [] 
  { 
    new Customer { Name = "Fred" }, 
    new Customer { Name = "Ginger" }
  }.ToList()
};
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
   context.Orders.Add(order);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This should all work as expected. It will save the new order and both associated customers.

However, if you load the order from the DbContext and want to manipulate the customers associated to it, then there are a couple caveats.
1. You should to eager-load the Customers collection so that EF knows about these entities.
2. You need to manipulate the collection with Add/Remove rather than setting the reference to avoid confusion about what the code looks like it does and what EF interprets.

Something like:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
   var order = context.Orders.Find(1);
   order.Customers = new [] 
   { 
      new Customer { Name = "Roy" }
   }.ToList();
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Will result in "Roy" being added to the Customers, rather than replacing them.

To replace them you need to remove them first, then add the new one.

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
   var order = context.Orders.Find(1);
   context.Customers.RemoveRange(order.Customers); // Assuming customers cannot exist without orders. If OrderId is nullable, this line can be omitted.
   order.Customers.Clear(); 
  order.Customers,Add(new Customer { Name = "Roy" });
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This starts to fall apart if the collections are not virtual. For instance:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
   var order = context.Orders.Find(1);
   order.Customers = new [] 
   { 
      new Customer { Name = "Roy" }
   }.ToList();
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

if the customers collection is virtual, after the SaveChanges, order.Customers will report a collection size of 3 elements. If it is not virtual it will report the size as 1 element even though there are 3 records now associated to the order in the DB. This leads to all kinds of issues where projects get caught out with invalid data state, duplicate records and the like.

Cases where you're seeing some records getting missed will likely be due to missing the virtual on the references, manipulating the collections outside of what EF is tracking, or other manipulations of the tracking state. (a common issue when projects are set up to detach/re-attach entities from contexts.)

Comment: This works when there is only one customer for the order. What if I have multiple customers link to this order? I do Customers = customers and it only saved the last one.

Comment: Added some detail on handling 1-many relationships and common pitfalls to check.